# How to render partial view inside href tag in .NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to render partial view on href tag but it is not working. Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong?

Appreciate you guidance and help.

In _Layout.cshtml

```
 <li>

   <a class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-3" href="#">Login / Signup</a>
   </li>
     @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

I want to render `_LoginPartial` on click of `Login/Signup`.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possibilities:

- You could render it by calling an action on the controller that returns the partial view.
- You could just render it as you did, but hide it with css. When the user click on the button you show the partial view via javascript.

The second is the easer than first one. For sample:

For sample, you could add a view and make it hidden by adding `display:none` via css.

```
<li>
   <a id="loginButton" class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-3" href="#">Login / Signup</a>
</li>

<div id="loginView" style="display:none;">
   @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

And add a click event on the login button on the javascript/jquery:

```
$("#loginButton").on("click", function() {
   $("#loginView").toggle();
});
```

The [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function will show if the element is hidden and vice-versa.

Comment: I am getting following error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toogle is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ((index):1233)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.js:5183)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.3.1.js:4991)`

Comment: I am sorry, the correct function is the `toggle()`. I just fixed it.